# Manually reorder stacked bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, stacked

I am trying to reorder my stacked bar plot so that it is from the bottom to top: Epidural, Subdural, Subarachnoid, Intracerebral, and Unspecified. I have included my plot, dataframe, and code below

[image]

This is my code:

```
ggplot(cat, aes(x = headbleed_trauma_primary, y = perc, fill = headbleed_category_primary))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack") + 
  theme_classic()
```

This is my data:

```
structure(list(headbleed_trauma_primary = c("Nontraumatic", "Nontraumatic", 
"Nontraumatic", "Nontraumatic", "Nontraumatic", "Traumatic", 
"Traumatic", "Traumatic"), headbleed_category_primary = c("Epidural", 
"Intracerebral", "Subarachnoid", "Subdural", "Unspecified", "Epidural", 
"Subarachnoid", "Subdural"), n = c(15L, 2848L, 1113L, 1295L, 
589L, 141L, 2078L, 3477L), perc = c(0.129802699896158, 24.6452059536172, 
9.63136033229491, 11.2062997577016, 5.0969193492558, 1.22014537902388, 
17.9820006922811, 30.0882658359294)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a `factor` variable and apply `ggplot`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

cat %>% 
  mutate(headbleed_category_primary = 
           factor(
             headbleed_category_primary,
             levels = c("Epidural", "Subdural", "Subarachnoid", "Intracerebral", "Unspecified")
             )
         ) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = headbleed_trauma_primary, y = perc, fill = headbleed_category_primary))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "stack") + 
  theme_classic()
```

This returns

[image: Plot of headbleed_trauma_primary]